# Input masking in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a textbox in the form, in which only specific number inputs are allowed. i.e

```
0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3........ and so on
```

How can i mask this textbox for these inputs? Or what regex should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to validate on submit, you can simply use `parseFloat`, `Math.floor` and `toString`:

```
function isValidValue(text) {
    return text == (Math.floor(parseFloat(text) * 2) / 2).toString();
}
```

Or you can perform a regex check with string replace, `.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "")`. That only allows numbers and periods/decimal points. **Unfortunately, it does not prevent multiple decimal points.**

If you want to restrict actual keystrokes, you need something more. Attach the following function to the `keyup` event for your textbox. Remember to use `return isValidKey(this, event)` instead of simply `isValidKey(this, event)`:

```
function isValidKey(me, evt) {

    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    var currValue = me.value;

    // disallow decimal point if it is not the first one
    if ((charCode == 46 || charCode == 110 || charCode == 190) && currValue.indexOf(".") != -1)
        return false;

    // disallow non numeric characters
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/SHJsz/

**Update:** It is now slightly more strict, but still not foolproof. You can still have a number with a leading 0 or start with a decimal point if the user uses backspace or delete to remove the original starting numbers.

http://jsfiddle.net/SHJsz/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are jquery plugins to handle masking an input.

[Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

You can look here:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

but it doesn't fully solve your problem, just allows a mask, not predefined values. You can modify the plugin code though for your needs.

For this control I would put the up and down arrow that increment/decrement and I would allow the free text that will validate on losing focus and round up the value to the nearest half. I think that would be most convenient. Masks could be annoying when they don't allow you to type text in.